# Send current Item and checkbox value in command parameters

Tags: wpf, treeview, multibinding, commandparameter

I have a `TreeView` setup with a `HierarchialDataTemplate`. It's `ItemsSource` is bound to a collection of `Overlay` objects in my viewmodel, where each `Overlay` has a collection of `Layer` objects (thus the `HierarchialDataTemplate`). For each `Overlay`, I'm displaying a `CheckBox` and a `Label` which is simply bound to the `Overlay`'s `Name` property.

What I'm trying to do is, each time one of the checkboxes is checked/unchecked, the current `Overlay` and the `IsChecked` property of the `CheckBox` will be sent as command parameters to my viewmodel.

If I'm not using the `MultiValueConverter`, I can send one of the properties fine. But I need to send both as parameters.

Below is the related .xaml for the treeview. I'm only showing the necessary parts and just the `Checked` trigger because the `Unchecked` is exactly the same:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding OverlaysViewSource}" Name="LayersTreeView">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Layers}" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="True">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.SetVisibilityCmd, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" >
                                    <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource multiValueConverter}">
                                            <Binding Path="IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=CheckBox}" />
                                            <Binding/>
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                                </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </CheckBox>
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

So in the `MultiBinding`, the first one: `<Binding Path="IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=CheckBox}" />` to try and send the checkbox's `IsChecked` property. However, the value I'm getting in the command is `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`.

The second one is just  for the current `Overlay` item, but the whole `TreeView` is being sent as a parameter.

Update:
The `Overlay` class is a third party control and is used in a lot of places that I can't modify. So I can't just add a property to it.

Update2: I've managed to get the `Overlay` to send properly. Just need the `IsChecked` property now.

Comment: Not sure of a solution yet, but here are couple things to try: First, you might have thought of this, but wouldn't declaring a property on `Overlay` and binding it to `IsChecked` be the easiest solution? Then you would only need one parameter. If you can't/won't do this for some reason, please include that in your question. Next, use `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High` to get a better idea of what your binding is trying to do. I might try `{RelativeSource Self}` in that first binding in the `MultiBinding`.

Comment: Updated my answer as to why I can't add a new property to `Overlay`. I feel like I'm missing something simple to send the current item as a parameter. Usually, it's something like `"{Binding}"` for the current source. Not sure how to put that in the `MultiBinding`.

Comment: Okay. Did you try `{RelativeSource Self}` for the `IsChecked` binding? Or `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High` to try and debug it?

Comment: Yup, just did! That seemed to work. If you want to put it as an answer I'll accept it. A new issue did come up regarding the `IsChecked` never changing, but I'm making a new question for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding for `IsChecked` should use `{RelativeSource Self}`, since the binding is being applied to the `CheckBox` via the `Style`.

Your update to your question shows you've already solved the other one.